# I have a text parameter in one stage of the Jenkins pipeline. How do I call it in the next stage?

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins, parameters

I have a text paramater as follows:
string1(name:'docker_images', defaultValue:'',description:'Enter the list of images').
This is in the jenkins pipeline in the stage called Parameters.
In the next stage , I need to call this parameter (below #CODE2) .
I have tried using the stash parameter but that does not accept string values. I do not know how else to call this text parameter.

```
parameters {
    
    text(name:'docker_images', defaultValue: NA, description:'Enter the list of images')
    
  }
  stages {
    
    stage(docker_image_movement){
      steps{
        container('tools'){
            #CODE1
                  script{
                    sh'''
                      #CODE2
                     
         
                      for docker_image in 'echo $docker_images'
                      do
                      #DOCKER COMMANDS
                      '''
                  }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant Pipeline code.

Comment: @ycr I have put up a snippet. I want to call the text parameter below the #CODE2.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have posted the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the shell block into double quotes for string interpolation to happen.

```
sh"""
    #CODE2
   

    for docker_image in $docker_images
    do
    #DOCKER COMMANDS
    
"""
```

You can loop through the input like below as well.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
     parameters { text(name: 'docker_images', defaultValue: 'One\nTwo\nThree\n', description: '') }
    stages {
        stage("Check") {
            steps {
                script {
                    for(def img in params.docker_images.split('\n')){
                        sh "echo  $img"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```